# Writing MA and AR representations

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive, moving-average-model

I have to determine if
$$(1 - 1.1B + 0.8B^2)Y_t = (1 - 1.7B + 0.72B^2)a_t$$

is stationary, invertible or both.

I have shown that $\Phi(B) = 1 - 1.1B + 0.8B^2 = 0$ when $B_{1,2} = 0.6875 \pm 0.8817i$, whose moduli are both larger than 1, hence is stationary. Similarly, I have shown that $\Theta(B) = 1 - 1.7B + 0.72B^2 = 0$, when $B_1 = 1.25 > 1$ and $B_2 = 1.11 > 1$, hence is invertible.

I also need to express the model as a MA and AR representation if it exists; which they do as I have already shown. However, to write as an MA process, I would need to write as:
$$Y_t = \frac{1 - 1.7B + 0.72B^2}{1 - 1.1B + 0.8B^2}a_t$$

and for an AR process as:
$$\frac{1 - 1.1B + 0.8B^2}{1 - 1.7B + 0.72B^2}Y_t = a_t$$

However, I am confused on how to do this given the division of the quadratic expressions. Should I use long division or is there some expansion formula I should be using?

Comment: Some quick points. (1) You can easily guess the roots of the bottom polynomial to be 0.8 and 0.9. (2) You can also see the top polynomial does not have real roots. Not sure if that helps at all, though :)

Comment: @RichardHardy I think the roots are correct: $1 - 1.7B + 0.72B^2 = (1 - 0.8B)(1 - 0.9B)$, which means that the roots are the reciprocals $1/0.8 = 1.25$ and $1/0.9 = 1.\overline{1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try the partial fraction decomposition:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1 - \alpha B)(1 - \beta B)} & = \frac{\alpha/(\alpha - \beta)}{1 - \alpha B} +  \frac{\beta/(\beta - \alpha)}{1 - \beta B} \\
& = (\alpha - \beta)^{-1} \left( \alpha(1 - \alpha B)^{-1} - \beta (1 - \beta B)^{-1} \right) \\
& = (\alpha - \beta)^{-1} \left( \alpha \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \alpha^k B^k - \beta \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \beta^k B^k \right) \\
& = (\alpha - \beta)^{-1} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (\alpha^{k+1} - \beta^{k+1}) B^k
\end{align}

and apply it to both cases like:
\begin{align}
\frac{1 + c B + d B^2}{(1 - \alpha B)(1 - \beta B)} & = (1 + c B + d B^2) (\alpha - \beta)^{-1} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (\alpha^{k+1} - \beta^{k+1}) B^k \\
& = (\alpha - \beta)^{-1} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (\alpha^{k+1} - \beta^{k+1}) (1 + c B + d B^2) B^k \\
& = (\alpha - \beta)^{-1} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (\alpha^{k+1} - \beta^{k+1}) (B^k + c B^{k+1} + d B^{k+2})
\end{align}
and by distributing and reindexing the summations, we have
\begin{align}
& = (\alpha - \beta)^{-1} \left( \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (\alpha^{k+1} - \beta^{k+1}) B^k + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty c (\alpha^k - \beta^k) B^k + \sum_{k = 2}^\infty d (\alpha^{k-1} - \beta^{k-1}) B^k) \right) \\
& = (\alpha - \beta)^{-1} \left( (\alpha - \beta) + (\alpha^2 - \beta^2 + c(\alpha - \beta)) B + \sum_{k = 2}^\infty [(\alpha^{k+1} - \beta^{k+1}) + c (\alpha^k - \beta^k) + d (\alpha^{k-1} - \beta^{k-1})] B^k \right) \\
& =  1 + (\alpha + \beta + c) B + (\alpha - \beta)^{-1} \sum_{k = 2}^\infty [(\alpha^{k+1} - \beta^{k+1}) + c (\alpha^k - \beta^k) + d (\alpha^{k-1} - \beta^{k-1})] B^k
\end{align}

Assuming I haven't made any mistakes, this gives the AR representation when $\alpha = 0.9$, $\beta = 0.8$, $c = -1.1$, and $d = 0.8$ and gives the MA process when $\alpha, \beta = 0.68750 \pm 0.88167 i$, $c = -1.7$, and $d = 0.72$. Perhaps you could even simplify this more using the [difference of nth powers formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_two_squares#Difference_of_two_nth_powers) (certainly you could cancel the $(\alpha - \beta)^{-1}$ term this way, but I don't know if you would call the result "simpler."